# JQuery - Having a button in a function that calls another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I couldn't seem to replicate the onclick event from a regular button to a function that also has a button with an onclick event.

I'm using:

```
<input type="button" name="passw" id="passw" value="Password" onclick="DisplayPassword();">
```

As my button to call this function:

```
function DisplayPassword(){
    DispWin = window.open('','toolbar=no,status=no')

    message="<form name=checkPW>";
    message+="<center><table cellpadding=30 border=1><tr><td><label>Password</label></td><td><input type=text name=password id=password></td></tr>";
    message+="<tr><td><input type=button value=Check onclick=CheckPassword()></td><td><input type=reset value=Clear></td></tr>";

    DispWin.document.write(message);
}
```

Which contains a button that I want to call another function to:

```
function CheckPassword(){
    DispWin = window.open('','toolbar=no,status=no')

    if(document.checkPW.password.value == 'yayy')
    {
        message="<h1><center>Correct Password!</center><h1>";
    }
    else
    {
        message="<input type=button value=Close onclick=self.close()>";
    }

    DispWin.document.write(message);
}
```

Comment: try this    message+="<tr><td><input type=button value=Check onclick=\"CheckPassword()\"></td><td><input type=reset value=Clear></td></tr>";

Comment: You're just creating a bunch of invalid html

Comment: I think the issue might be because the checkPassword is not included in quotes. so try adding them in quotes along with escape character

Answer (score 0):

First, the HTML you're writing to the `DispWin` popup is not valid and missing the closing tags for `<form>`, `<center>`, and `<table>` tags.

Now, to call a JavaScript function from the button on the `DispWin` popup, you need to write the function to the popup:

```
message+="<script>function CheckPassword(){";
message+="DispWin = window.open('','toolbar=no,status=no');";
message+="if(document.checkPW.password.value == 'yayy') {message='<h1><center>Correct Password!</center><h1>';}";
message+="else {message='<input type=button value=Close onclick=self.close()>';}";
message+="DispWin.document.write(message);}";
DispWin.document.write(message);
```

Keep in mind that popup windows are very annoying to the user and might get blocked by some browsers. Consider using `div` popups instead.